# how to initialize PostgreSQL database on startup from the SQL script in the resource for Spring Boot app

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I have a list of SQL scripts in the resource folder. There is a list of scripts from 01 to 06. It must be inserted sequentially. I tried with following application.properties:-

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=docker
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Here is screenshot for the list script in the resoure folder:-

[image]

The app is running without any error. But it did not populate the database. How do I populate it?

Comment: Seems like you really ought to be using Flyway.

Comment: Can u pls refer to any tuorial or blogs to read more about it.